# Open server не сохраняет настройки my.ini

Tags: openserver

Редактирую файл `my.ini` в папке mysql-5.6 и перезагружаю сервер, после перезагрузки все изменения пропадают. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А Вы попробуйте через меню openserver открыть конфиг и там уже редактировать.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо все сработало!

Answer (score 2):

OpenServer - это удобная настройка и конфигами он сам "подруливает". Поэтому он будет перетирать то, что он считает "своим".  Это очень удобно, потому что если в какой то версии поменяется настройка php или базы данных, это можно красиво припрятать.

Поэтому, все такие настройки нужно менять через меню openserver, которое для это предназначено.